# Delete values in a column from another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

Is there a formula that I can use to automatically delete the values that appear in column D from column A?

[image]

So that my final column A will look like this?:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Formulas cannot delete data.

Comment: Not seen where formula has deleted data, perhaps you could use a formula to extract the desired outputs: `=FILTER(A2:A14,ISNA(XMATCH(A2:A14,D2:D6)))` or `=FILTER(A2:A14,COUNTIFS(D2:D6,A2:A14)=0)`

Comment: You can either filter using a formula and output the result to a new range - or you will need vba to physically remove values from the range

Comment: This takes a few steps, but in Column B1 type "Delete", and in the rest of Column B use `=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2,D:D,0)),"Delete",ROW(A2))` to flag which values should be deleted. Then use Data tab > Remove Duplicates > Column B to remove all the values that have been flagged "Delete".